# my cod blackops online prestiges are gone

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

yesterday I have started the game and I have seen that my blackops online level is 0 all of my scores(prestiges also) had gone. I was prestige 10 and level 34. What can be the problem here and how can I get back my scores?

Comment: You might want to contact [Activision Customer Support](https://activision.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/activision.cfg/php/enduser/ask.php) about that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i have submitted my problem on that link.

Comment: It's possible you've played on a hacked server, which has reset your prestige

Comment: I have also heard of a prestige reset happening from an offensive player emblem / clan tag

Comment: @Anzeo maybe I don't know. @Joel Briggs no I did not have that kind amblem or clantag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted to Activison Support and they've sent this respnse.

> Thank you for contacting Activision!
>   Sounds like you have a network
>   communication failure with the
>   servers. Any sort of interrupted
>   communication that occurs when the
>   game is processing or updating stats
>   can result in a reset or rollback;
>   It's generally due to factors beyond
>   your control. The servers will have to
>   work to retrieve your stats, and this
>   may take some time. This is no
>   estimated time for the retrieval.

Now my prestiges are back :)